# Parsing a JSON object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON Object:

```
[{"id":"123","username":"test"}]
```

I want to parse `username` using javascript so i did this

```
var content = '[{"id":"123","username":"test"}]
obj = JSON.parse(content)
alert(obj.username)
```

I get an alert: `undefined`

I've tried parsing the JSON without the `[ ]` and it worked

For example:

```
var content = '{"id":"123","username":"test"}'
obj = JSON.parse(content)
alert(obj.username)
```

My question would be how would i parse the JSON with the [ ] tags around it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because `[]` makes it an array.  Try `alert(obj[0].username)`.

If you changed your JSON to look like this...

```
[ {"id":"123","username":"test"}, {"id":"456","username":"test 2"}]
```

Then `alert(obj[1].username)` would be `test 2`, and `alert(obj[0].username)` would be `test`.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried using alert(obj[1].username) but it didn't work. I was wondering why it didn't. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The undefined error you get in the first case is because the JSON represents an ARRAY with a single object in it.  In order to access the username you would need `alert(obj[0].username)`