# Parsing a JSON object with escaped double quote attributes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

After [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056563/parsing-a-json-object-in-javascript) a [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559625/javascript-escape-double-quotes) on parsing an object in javascript I'm still having issues with parsing the following query response:

```
{"messagesProfile": "[{\"message\": \"This is a test message\", \"sender\": \"test@test.com\", \"receiver
\": \"test@test.com\"}, {\"message\": \"This is a second test message\", \"sender\": \"test@test.com
\", \"receiver\": \"test@test.com\"}, {\"message\": \"This is a third test message\", \"sender\": \"test
@test.com\", \"receiver\": \"test@test.com\"}]", "successProfileMessages": true}
```

The code that parses the above response is:

```
if(data.successProfileMessages === false) {
            alert("Failed to retrieve messages");
        } else {
            if(typeof data.messagesProfile != "undefined" && data.messagesProfile != null && data.messagesProfile.length > 0) {
                messages = messages + "<tr>";
                messages = messages + "<td>";
                messages = messages + "There are no messages yet!";
                messages = messages + "</td>";
                messages = messages + "<td>";
            } else {
                // Successfully retrieved messages
                for(var i in  data) {
                    messages = messages + "<tr>";
                    messages = messages + "<td>";
                    messages = messages + data.messagesProfile.sender[i];
                    messages = messages + "</td>";
                    messages = messages + "<td>";
                    messages = messages + data.messagesProfile.message[i];
                    messages = messages + "</td>";
                    messages = messages + "</tr>";
                }
            }
        }
```

How is it possible to unescape the escaped double quotes and iterate through the JSON object's array fields?

```
"[{\"message\": \"This is a test message\", \"sender\": \"test@test.com\", \"receiver
\": \"test@test.com\"}, {\"message\": \"This is a second test message\", \"sender\": \"test@test.com
\", \"receiver\": \"test@test.com\"}, {\"message\": \"This is a third test message\", \"sender\": \"test
@test.com\", \"receiver\": \"test@test.com\"}]"
```

Comment: define 'having issues'? I assume you're parsing first with `JSON.parse()` before iterating over the data?

Comment: Yes the response is parsed with JSON.parse() but still the first branch in the if is taken.

Comment: That code assumes your JSON is **already parsed**. I think your question has nothing to do with JSON in the first place—you probably just want to iterate through a JavaScript data structure.

Comment: Removed the json tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the messageProfile property of `data` is a string so you need to parse it

you can do this in the `else` clause

```
var arrayResult = JSON.parse(data.messagesProfile);
for (var i = 0, len = arrayResult.length; i < len; i++) {
  var item = arrayResult[i];
  // do your stuff
}
```

For iterating over an array i discourage the use of `for (var i in arrayResult)` cause it will not give you the desired result. It will iterate through all the properties of the object (including the length property!!!!!)

Comment: That did it. I've messed up the if.